# why MutableLiveData setValue don't work when getting the response from retrofit2.Callback

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am developing an android app. I make a call to the REST API using the retrofit2 and I am trying to get the response. I can see I am getting the response on `onResponse()` but the `val` data which is a MutableLiveData is not getting the value when I assign it on `onResponse()` `data.value = response.body()?.currently`

```
override fun getSavedCurrentForecast(): LiveData<CurrentResponse> {

    val data = MutableLiveData<CurrentResponse>()
    val forecast = retrofitClient.getForecast(locationDataStore?.location)

    forecast.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<ForecastResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ForecastResponse>,
            response: Response<ForecastResponse>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Timber.d("response: ${response.body()?.currently}")
                data.value = response.body()?.currently
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ForecastResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Timber.d("onFailure: $t")
        }

    })
    return data
}
```

I know I am getting the response but the method still return null. I would appreciate help guys and please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: From different thread you should rather use postValue, also how you check if there is no value?.. You should use observe, as obviously right after this call there will be no value

Comment: thanks for your comment, Not from a different thread. the onResponse runs on the main thread so setvalue should be fine. You said how you check if there is no value basically when I call this method the return value is null. how should use observe here?

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize MutableLiveData when you have the result

```
var data: MutableLIveData<CurrentResponse> = null //or lateinit

...

data = MutableLiveData<CurrentResponse>(response.body()?.currently)
```

or you can try to do postValue instead of setValue. In this way, the observer is  notified

```
data.postValue(response.body()?.currently)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Timber.d("response: ${response.body()?.currently}")
            data.postvalue = response.body()?.currently
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.